Is it safe to soldering while a device is connected to a PC or laptop with USB?
I'm not a professional on soldering or electronics but have a pair of joysticks need some repair via re-connecting some of broken solders. Did it before but didn't concern that could damage my laptop or PC, because I did it while joystick was connected to PC or laptop.
The process is I connect joysticks to PC or Laptop and open a software there that shows connection status of hardware, which helps me to find when device is connected or soldered properly.
All I'm asking, is it possible that soldering device make an unwanted input voltage to power of PC or laptop to apply a damage to PC or laptop?
My soldering device a cheap common one you can buy anywhere!

No, not safe.
Is it possible to damage PC, yes it is.
Did any damage happen, we cannot know. It is possible nothing happened even if there was a possibility for something to happen.
Now, apparently you managed to do the soldering, nothing got short circuited and PC and joystick still communicates OK.
What could have happened is that you could have shorted supply wire to a data wire or a ground wire, which might have burned up the supply or data section of that port.
Or the soldering iron tip could have been charged with static electricity and do some ESD damage if it was not weakly grounded for ESD safety.
If the soldering iron tip were bonded tight to ground, touching the USB VBUS might have damaged the supply with short circuit to ground.
If the solering iron has a floating power supply with and Y capacitor between mains and low voltage side for EMI management, the soldering tip could have few tens of volts AC through the capacitor, and touching a sensitive data line where the capacitor can discharge may damage the USB chipset.
Since there is always a risk for damage, it might not be a good idea to solder live circuits, espcially if you want to keep your laptop or the USB ports working.

This is so detailed and taught me a lot.
Appreciate your explanations!

Also a whole lot of components (most types?) can't handle operating during some 250°C temperature even for a short moment and might take permanent damage from that alone.

Soldering irons can have grounded tips which could short out any circuits they touch. Don't risk it; removing the USB plug from the computer before soldering things on the game controller and then reinserting the USB plug back into the computer once you have finished soldering is an easy insurance policy.

Plugging a USB plug out, you mean?

Yes, thank you.
